# How to not let visitors to view website, if they are connecting with IE

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

is there a possible way, to not let customers view website with internet explorer? I mean, i want to cause error, if visitor is connecting to website with internet explorer? And, if it is a possible way, how can i do it with PHP or HTML (if possible)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you google this? I know the answer is out there on lots and lots of websites.

Comment: yes i did, but maybe my english skills is not very good for terms.

Comment: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/how_to_detect_internet_explorer_with_php.xml

Comment: and no one has pointed out this is just a bad idea? A good website is browser agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // do redirect or throw exception etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you:

```
<?php
    function detect_msie()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
            (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can understand your problems with English.
[This site](http://www.devin.com/ieblock_howto.shtml) suggests this PHP code, and also shows a JavaScript approach (along with several others).

```
<?php
   if (eregi("MSIE",getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT")) ||
       eregi("Internet Explorer",getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))) {
    Header("Location: http://www.domain.com/ie_reject.html");
    exit;
   }
?>
```

[This other site](http://callumpy.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-block-internet-explorer-from-your-site/) has humorous and rude messages to display (which I don't recommend for you!) which you can edit to suit your site. You download the script from there.